# I have problem in android studio with making timer

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

In the app, I reopen the same activity that the timer is in. The first time timer works but after that it starts bugging the Runs `onFinish()` at random time. How can I fix that?

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textQuestion.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        wrongAnswer();
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: That can;t be possible your onFinish will be called after 10 second you started timer

Comment: Try with Logging value of millisUntilFinished inside onTick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must store CountDownTimer in timer and cancel it when you move to another activity or fragment ;

Create `CountDownTimer` as global variable(above onCreate)

```
CountDownTimer timer;
```

Initialize timer where you want start a timer or whenever

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textQuestion.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            wrongAnswer();
        }
    }.start();
```

And in `onDestroy` cancel it

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(timer != null) timer.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: It shows Overriding method should call super.OnDestroy().